# Erro do gdrive no crontab

Tags: backup, google-drive-api, cron

Estou tentando realizar uma maneira de realizar um backup utilizando mysql e transferir os dados para a nuvem do google drive. Estou utilizando o *mysqldump* para realizar o backup e o *gdrive* para dar upload na nuvem.

https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive

E para automatizar estou utilizando o *crontab* do linux. Abaixo está o exemplo que estou utilizando para realizar tal funcionalidade.

```
11 08 * * * root mysqldump -u root *senha* *database* | gzip > .../caminho/backup$(date +\$Y_\%m_\%d_\%H).sql.gz
```

.

```
11 08 * * * root gdrive upload -r /caminho/backup_auto_$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d_\%H).sql.gz -p hash_diretorio
```

O backup do *mysqldump* funciona legalzinho. Porém o *gdrive* não dá o upload na nuvem. Testando manualmente fora do *crontab* dá certo. Já executei vários tutoriais referentes ao assunto como forma de solução e mesmo assim não funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O melhor tutorial que vi para utilizar esse recurso foi esse abaixo.

https://medium.com/auto-backup-mysql-to-google-drive/auto-backup-mysql-to-google-drive-c8b2178b097e

Para se instalar de maneira correta e que funcione no crontab do linux. Deve ser transferido o executavel do gdrive para o diretorio /usr/bin. Utilizando o homebrew do linux não irá funcionar dessa maneira citada.
O certo seria baixar o executável para a tua maquina, mudar o nome desse executável para gdrive (comando mv), e assim dar um *cp gdrive /user/bin*.

Aonde deve ser baixado o executável:
https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive

Também tem outra alternativa nesse tutorial logo acima.